# NullPointerException while using <security:authentication> under JBoss 6.1

Tags: jsp, jboss, spring-security

I have got NullPointerException while using  in my JSP under JBoss 6.1

I am using spring 3.0.5.RELEASE (spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE)

My app works great on JBoss 5

But after moving to JBoss 6 NPE appears

Did anyone experience such problem?

Log:

**root cause**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jsp Error(DefaultErrorHandler.java:51)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.start Element(JspDocumentParser.java:429)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startE lement(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Unless you have not provided the complete stack trace, this has nothing to do with Spring Security. It looks like a JSP compilation problem. What makes you think it has anything to do with Spring Security?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes it seems like a JSP render bug, but when i remove the <security:authentication> tag from the JSP the bug disappeares. It make me think that the problem not in the Spring Security but in the Spring Security Tag Library. I have tried older versions of the Spring Security Tag Library but the bug still exists

Comment: How are you referencing the Spring Security tag library at the top of the page? Can you provide the exact code that you are adding / removing to "fix" this issue?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

<security:authentication property="principal" var="userLogined"/>

<jsp:output
omit-xml-declaration="true"
doctype-root-element="html"
doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>

<title>${pageTitle}</title>

Comment: <security:authentication property="principal" var="userLogined"/>

Comment: The problem is with this string

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=359881&posted=1#post359881

Comment: Answering you in the forum. Once / if we arrive at a conclusion, I will post back here @ SO.

Comment: I finally fixed the problem
I was right the point was in the tld 
 Spring Security TLD needs to be patched